# Method for testing interaction in regression analysis

Tags: regression, interaction, regression-strategies

I am running a linear model with 6 explanatory variables (5 in classes, 1 quantitative), and would like to test which interaction(s) are eventually significant.
I think an ascendant stepwise method could do the job, but wonder if there could be more advanced (and perhaps more simple/shorter) methods.

I am also wondering, in the case of an interaction between two variables, if there exists methods to create a combined variable, with grouped modalities to put in the model in replacement of the two variables (and to test if such a variable would be more relevant than the interaction itself).

Comment: This is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks. I am not myself convinced by what I propose but ... Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Have a look at https://towardsdatascience.com/stopping-stepwise-why-stepwise-selection-is-bad-and-what-you-should-use-instead-90818b3f52df